# BigQuery DNN model constant deviation

Tags: deep-learning, google-bigquery, machine-learning-model

I'm using DNN model with the following hyperparameter:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `External_Sources.DNN_REGRESSOR`
OPTIONS(MODEL_TYPE='DNN_REGRESSOR',
       ACTIVATION_FN = 'RELU',
        BATCH_SIZE = 200,
        HIDDEN_UNITS = [200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200],
        INPUT_LABEL_COLS = ['questions_cnt_users'],
        LEARN_RATE=0.001
                )AS
SELECT * FROM `data`
```

The features contain 400K rows and these columns `country_code, weekday, year, type`.
country_code and type is a categorial variable.

I run my data on this model and afterward I **filter only US country** then I make a prediction VS actual chart
[image]
and the model show a great result to predict the time series but if you look at the chart you can see that a regular raise will produce a better prediction. The question is how can I make the model go up and the data day regularly in some countries and in other countries go down?

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve. Please elaborate on it. Did you have any issues or are you looking for Best Practice or advice?

Comment: Please notice that the prediction line is under the actual data (the gap is constant), so how can I remove this gap? any hyperparameters changes, please advice

Comment: It might be hard to find solution via Stackoverflow as some of your Private information will be required to replicate/advise with this issue. You should consider to reach Google via [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker#public_users) or [Google Support](https://support.google.com/).